# Leaflet (markerCluster + searchControl): How to spiderfy cluster before opening popup when searching

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i am working on my leaflet project. I am using Leaflet search together with Leaflet-markerCluster.
Some of my markers are on exact same coordinates. Everything if working fine, if marker which i am searching for is not in cluster (i am opening popup when marker is found).
When i am searching for marker which is in cluster, it wont open if cluster wasnt opened before.
So if I am right, i need to open cluster, before Popup is opened. But I dont know how to do it :) Can anyone help me with this? Thank you

Here is code of markerCluster and searchControl:

```
    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({ maxClusterRadius: 30 });
    markers.addLayer(featuresLayer);
    mymap.addLayer(markers);

    var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
    layer: L.featureGroup([markers]),
    propertyName: 'name',
    marker: false,
    });

    searchControl.on('search:locationfound', function(e) {
    if (e.layer._popup)
    e.layer.openPopup();

    }).on('search:collapsed', function(e) {
    featuresLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    featuresLayer.resetStyle(layer);
    });
    });

    mymap.addControl(searchControl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add zoomToShowLayer method to your listener?

```
markers.zoomToShowLayer(marker, function () {
                    marker.openPopup();
                });
```